# Find all solutions for vector (r-a) cross (r-b) = (0,0,0),

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Find all solutions of (r − a) × (r − b) = (0, 0, 0),
where a = (a1, a2, a3) and b = (b1, b2, b3) are given vectors. I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $$|\vec v\times\vec u|=|\vec v|\cdot |\vec u|\cdot\sin(\theta)$$ What can you say about $\vec v$ and $\vec u$ if $\vec v\times \vec u=\vec 0$?